# Condition inside forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays:

```
firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
secondArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];
```

I must use their elements to compute another one inside a forEach.

```
_.forEach(firstArray, (data, i) => {
myValue: firstArray[i] + secondArray[i]
});
```

This works fine. But I want to ignore the last element of the second array all the time. So in this case, for `i = 3` the result should be `4`, not `4+8`, ignoring the last value of the second array.

I know that using an `if` statement wouldn't work but is there a way to do it?

I mean inside the forEach, removing the last element before the function doesn't work in this case.

**UPDATE**: I received some good answers but all of them were using something different than `forEach`. I would like to know if there is a way to do it with this function or not.

Comment: Check if i == 3 or i == firstArray.length then do firstArray[i] + 0

Comment: Have a look at the answer to see how to use `forEach`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check if `i` is the last element of the second array using `array.length`.

I don't really understand your `forEach` code, but you could use ternary operators in it:

```
_.forEach(firstArray, (data, i) => {
    myValue: firstArray[i] + (i === secondArray.length - 1 ? 0 : secondArray[i])
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`

```
firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
secondArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];
var output = firstArray.map( ( s, i, ar ) => s + (i == ar.length - 1 ?  0 : secondArray[i] ) );
```

> UPDATE: I received some good answers but all of them were using
>   something different than forEach. I would like to know if there is a
>   way to do it with this function or not.

using `forEach`, you would need **another array to capture the sum**

```
firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
secondArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];
var myValue = [];
firstArray.map( ( s, i, ar ) => myValue.push( s + (i == ar.length - 1 ?  0 : secondArray[i] ) ) );
```

now `myValue` is

> [6, 8, 10, 4]

Hence `map` seems to be a less-verbose approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce and map the arrays.

```js
var firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    secondArray = [5, 6, 7, 8],
    result = [firstArray, secondArray].reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + b[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
secondArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];

for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++){
    if(i === firstArray.length - 1) {
         myValue = firstArray[i];
    } else {
        myValue = firstArray[i] + secondArray[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i === firstArray.length - 1`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Forgot such a basic thing :-)